# Backtracking - Generate Sudokuarray

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, sudoku, generate

i want to generate a simple Sudokugenerator using backtrack. I am stuck / don't know if i used backtracking properly. **zahlIstGueltigAufPosition** returns if the number **zahl** is valid (if zahl appears once in the row/column or one of the 9 Boxes).

```
public static boolean fuelleArray(int y, int x, int zahl){

    sudokuArray[y][x]=zahl;


    if(zahlIstGueltigAufPosition(y,x,zahl)){

        if(x==8 && y<=7 && fuelleArray(y+1,0,1)){
            return true;

        }else if(x==8 && y==8 && fuelleArray(y,x,zahl)) {
            return true;

        }else if(x<=7 && y<=8){
            if(fuelleArray(y,x+1,1)) {
                return true;
            }
       }
    }else{
        if(zahl<9 && x<=8 && y<=8 ){fuelleArray(y,x,zahl+1);}
    }

    return false;
}
```

The Program gives out:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 4 5 6 1 2 3 9 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: First of all, please format your code.  I can't read it with such an absence of spaces.  Second of all, you've not told us what is wrong with this code.  Please [edit] your question to provide this information.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry, its updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is my solution, there are better ways you can use backtracking to generate sudoku, like just calling *fuelleArray(fieldIndex, numberInField)*. 
With that, backtracking would be more visible and clear in the code and you won't have to deal, like I had, with the cases when its on the end of a row.

```
public static boolean fuelleArray(int y, int x, int zahl){

    sudokuArray[y][x]=zahl;

    if(zahlIstGueltigAufPosition(y,x,zahl)){
                                       //#1
        if(x==8 && y<=7){              //if you aren't at the end
            if(fuelleArray(y+1,0,1)){  //look if the the next field
                return true;           //is correct
            }
                                       //#2
        }else if(x==8 && y==8){        //if I am at the end 
            return true;               //return true, cause at 
                                       //zahlIstGueltigAufPosition
                                       //we know its correctly plassed               
                                       //by the SudokuRules


        }else if(x<=7 && y<=8){        //Just like #1, but there it
            if(fuelleArray(y,x+1,1)){  //was to handle the end of a 
                return true;           //row

            }
        }
    }

    if(zahl<9 && x<=8 && y<=8 ){      //if we are not correct we
        if(fuelleArray(y,x,zahl+1)){  //increase the number in that
            return true;              //field

        }
    }else {                           //if we are at number 9 we put 
        sudokuArray[y][x]=0;          //put it back to zero
                                      //
    }                                 //
    return false;                     //and return false

}
```